# How can a correlated subquery inside a SELECT's CASE WHEN access outer table alias?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 12.  I've contrived a simplistic example to try to convey the problem I'm facing as the actual query is too complex to present here.  This simplistic example contains the same conditions and logic that the complex query has.  I'm hoping to find a way for a subquery that is in a WHEN within the main SELECT to access a table alias that is defined from an inner join that is at the same level as the main SELECT.  I tried this version but it fails with the 'o' "table or view does not exist":

```
 SELECT emp.employeeid, emp.firstname
 CASE 
 WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM o WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
 WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM o WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
 ELSE 'No'
 END AS "Quota Met"
 FROM Employee emp
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT employeeid, shipperid FROM Orders 
  WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30) o
  ON o.employeeid = emp.id
 WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151;
```

Unable to get the INNER JOIN version above to work, my best workaround so far is to define the SELECT using the WITH feature like below, but in the real query the WITH block takes several minutes to complete since there is no way to restrict it to match against the Employee.employeeid like the above INNER JOIN version attempts.

```
 WITH MyOrders AS
 (SELECT employeeid, shipperid FROM Orders 
  WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30
 )
 SELECT emp.id, emp.name, o
  CASE 
   WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyOrders o WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
   WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyOrders o WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
  ELSE 'No'
  END AS "Quota Met"
 FROM Employee emp
 WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151;
```

Is this WITH version really the best solution?  Is there any way to rewrite the first INNER JOIN version so that the subquery in the CASE WHEN can access the joined table alias?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the subqueries; if you move the `o.shipperid <= 15` check into the inline view then you can can just count the matches from the join. I've changed your inner join to an outer join so you'll see 'No' for zero counts - otherwise there would be no match and that employee wouldn't be shown at all.

```
SELECT emp.employeeid, emp.firstname,
   CASE 
     WHEN count(o.shipperid) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
     WHEN count(o.shipperid) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
     ELSE 'No'
   END AS "Quota Met"
FROM Employee emp
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT employeeid, shipperid
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30
  AND o.shipperid <= 15
) o
ON o.employeeid = emp.id
WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151
GROUP BY emp.employeeid, emp.firstname;
```

As this is aggregating you need the `group by` clause too; which might be more problematic for your real, more complicated query.

If you can't move that condition in your more complicated query because you're using other data from `o` where that isn't met, then you can use conditional aggregation with more case expressions:

```
SELECT emp.employeeid, emp.firstname,
   CASE 
     WHEN count(CASE WHEN o.shipperid <= 15 THEN o.shipperid END) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
     WHEN count(CASE WHEN o.shipperid <= 15 THEN o.shipperid END) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
     ELSE 'No'
   END AS "Quota Met"
FROM Employee emp
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT employeeid, shipperid
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30
) o
ON o.employeeid = emp.id
WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151
GROUP BY emp.employeeid, emp.firstname;
```

You may still want that to be an outer join, but if not just change that back to an inner one.

Comment: Your suggestions look promising and give me hope.  Am trying to apply them now...

Comment: Thank you. I was able to apply your suggestions to restructure the query to avoid the failure I was seeing.  I then realized that restructuring the query to get the JOIN to work didn't achieve my ultimate goal of speeding up the query.  That derived table that I was JOINing to is independent of the field(s) ON which it is joined to the main query; I'd forgotten that that JOINed table has to be set and defined before the JOIN can work, so my attempt to limit it by the JOIN itself didn't make sense.  Your ideas helped me see my options for restructuring though that I hadn't thought of before.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accessing to the outer subquery  as  table  you must repeat the code

```
SELECT emp.employeeid
, emp.firstname
, CASE 
  WHEN (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM  (
    SELECT employeeid, shipperid 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30
    ) o 
    WHERE o.shipperid <= 15
  ) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
WHEN (
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM  (
    SELECT employeeid, shipperid 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30
    ) o
    WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No' END AS "Quota Met"
FROM Em  ployee emp
INNER JOIN  (
SELECT employeeid, shipperid 
FROM Orders 
WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30

) o ON o.employeeid = emp.id
WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151;
```

if don't want repeat the code you could use a view

```
create my_view as  
SELECT employeeid, shipperid 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE orderdate > sysdate - 30


SELECT emp.employeeid
, emp.firstname
, CASE 
  WHEN (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM my_view o
    WHERE o.shipperid <= 15
  ) > 10 THEN 'Almost'
WHEN (
  SELECT count(*) 
  FROM  my_view o
    WHERE o.shipperid <= 15) > 20 THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No' END AS "Quota Met"
FROM Em  ployee emp
INNER JOIN  my_viewq o ON o.employeeid = emp.id
WHERE emp.zipcode = 22151;
```

Comment: The problem is that this SELECT is huge when not restricted with a matching employeeid, and takes over 15 minutes to complete.  That's 15 minutes if I use the WITH (like a view) or 30 minutes if I copy the SELECT to both locations - which I tried earlier.  I'm trying to avoid the SELECT being executed without the employeeid match condition so that it doesn't select the millions of records it finds otherwise.